# Apple doesn't guarantee delivery of pushes?

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, openssl, push-notification

Sometimes my script, that sends push notifications crashes with error:

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL
>   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake
>   failure

And sometimes everything is ok. I think this is not connected with certs or code. Cause I'm sending the same messages to the same devices and use the same algorithm. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question in the title - no, there's no guarantee that notifications will arrive.